# Clear instruction for building an iOS version of a Flutter app

Tags: xcode, flutter, macos, dart

I have a flutter project which I developed in VSCode and Windows. Now I want to have an iOS output and I am very new to macOS. I did not find any clear instructions to follow from scratch. I cloned my project onto a Mac. I don't know which folder to open and how to get started? As I finished the development step, do I need to install Flutter on Mac? Are there any clear instructions?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to have flutter set up on mac. The tutorial I use everytime and everytime it works is [here](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=hL7pkX1Pfko).

You will also need an xcode that's compatible with your current OS. If you have the latest macOS you can just get it from appstore. If not then get it from [here](https://developer.apple.com/xcode/resources/). (you'll need developer account for that, but the free tier works at this step)

After downloading and installing xCode you'll have app called Emulator installed automatically. This app is even more important than xcode itself for development & testing. With this app you can create virtual iOS devices to build and test your app on ( yes it works with vs code when running `flutter run` command).

Basic rule when developing on mac is- edit flutter elsewhere. xCode does not want to have anything to do with external code- it can only launch the `ios` folder in your project (which is also important for signing the app/ publishing and testing on real physical devices).